# Black Diamond Questions Marks - Youtube API - J�r�my

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api

when I try send the following to Youtube Description via API - for example: `Jérémy` - I get `J�r�my` in the youtube description. Strangely , `"–"` also shows as `"�"`.

Im posting with `PHP Zend` API :

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('Jérémy');
```

Im not sure if I can set encoding? When I change the description manually it works fine.

**ANSWER  - Changed Page Properties in Dreamweaver to UTF8 and problem solved. Thanks all**

Comment: What editor are you using when you write your code? I once had this issue an discovered that in Notepad++ the page encoding was set to ANSI and not UTF8 as I needed.

Comment: Depending on the version of PHP you're using, you might run into character encoding issues (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571694/what-factors-make-php-unicode-incompatible).

Comment: @Skuli: That's almost certainly the issue: YouTube is expecting a UTF-8 string, but the OP's code is saved in some other charset (most likely ISO Latin 1 or Windows-1252).  You might want to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What editor are you using when you write your code? I once had this issue an discovered that in Notepad++ the page encoding was set to ANSI and not UTF8 as I needed.

This could also be an duplicate from:   [not being displayed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609491/nbsp-not-being-displayed-properly). Check out the answer from [GmonC to that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609990/498596).

Comment: Hi ,Im entering directly in Dreamweaver. I actually noticed that PSPAD ( editor i use ) was set to ANSI so changed to UTF8 and retried( copied into PSPAD , then to Dreamweaver )  but this didnt work.Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but as you are sending a string it might mean you will need to use the ascii code for "special" characters as they will be evaluated as is when rendered by the browser.

for example for é you could use:

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('J&#233;r&#233;my');
```

and for a dash you could/would use: '&#45';

Comment: Thank you , just tried that but it sends directly the values as presented. J&#233;r&#233;my is shown.