# api response shows some black rectangles and question marks inside it

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, openkm

I have been using openKM for document management and after retrieving image from openkm using api it shows question marks [rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS2X3.png).

I have already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073845/black-diamond-questions-marks-youtube-api-jrmy)  but did not help
.

my python code for making api request

any help will be much appreciated

```
url = "http://ipaddress/aa18be7a5/hhhhhggg.png"

payload={}
headers = {'Internal-Key':"gjffhddsgsgdfgkhkhggdgsfd"}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
return response.text
```

Comment: well, a PNG is binary data after all

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX can you be more specific please on how to display it on html

Comment: display it as an `<img` I guess - since a `.png` is traditionally an image format - as you've shown zero code from the browser side, it's hard to tell you what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You requested .PNG data, and that's what the server sent you.
It all looks good.

You did this

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, ...)
return response.text
```

The request is beautiful.

But then you looked at `.text`, hoping for some unicode.
That would make sense, on a text document.
But instead you obtained a binary PNG document.
Just look at the returned headers -- they will
explain that its "Content-type" is "image/png".

You want `response.content` instead,
which is uninterpreted binary bytes,
suitable for writing to some "foo.png" file for display.
(Remember to use `"wb"` as the open() mode, not just `"w"`!)

It's important to understand that some byte strings
do not form valid utf-8, and trying to treat
binary images as unicode will soon end in tears.

Comment: Thank you so much  @J_H  I have added `'Content-Type': 'image/png'`  and
 `return response.content` instead now I get this numbers array sorry I am a kinda new to Python. and I don't have file path for open() function what should I pass instead of file path?

Comment: I can save image using the following code but what I want is to return the image back to js response and preview it there using img tag 

`response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
with open(get_file_path('filename.png'), 'wb') as f:
response.raw.decode_content = True
shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)`

Comment: converted arrayBuffer to base64 and now it is working  thanks alot @J_H